# What is the life cycle of a simple dialog in android?

Tags: android

There is a life cycle of a dialog in android When is is created, attached to activity or window, dismissed and resumed. And when is it created?

Comment: I pushed it up - because I was wondering the same question, a time ago...
I'm sure this will help you out:
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidDialogs/article.html